# How do I emulate this "docker run" command in a docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

### docker run command

I'm using the following command to launch a Docker container.

```
    docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 \
        -v ~/dev/react-using-camera/.nginx-conf-for-container/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
        -v ~/dev/nginx-test-area:/usr/share/nginx/html/ \
        --name web \
        nginx:stable-alpine
```

The command works satisfactorily:

- the container launches;
- nginx responds to requests and
- the config and web pages used by nginx are those present in the host directories as defined by the '-v' arguments.

### Using 'docker-compose up'

I would like to achieve the same effect by using `docker-compose up` and so I have written the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  ingress:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: docker-compose-test-0
    networks:
      - gateway
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/glaucon/dev/react-using-camera/.nginx-conf-for-container/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /home/glaucon/dev/nginx-test-area:/usr/share/nginx/html/ \

networks:
  gateway: {}
```

When I use that file with `docker-compose up` :

- the container launches
- nginx responds to requests but
- the web content served is **not** that present in `/home/glaucon/dev/nginx-test-area` on the host machine, instead the nginx default `index.html` is served.

### Question

How may I emulate the use of the '-v' arguments in my `docker run` command in the context of `docker-compose up` ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the \ on the 2nd volume mount?

Comment: @Turing85 Aaaagh ! I have been looking at this for a long time ... thank you. Would you turn your comment into an answer and I can mark it as the answer ? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `volume`-definition has a trailing backslash:

```
services:
  ingress:
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - /home/glaucon/dev/nginx-test-area:/usr/share/nginx/html/ \
```

If we remove the trailing backslash:

```
services:
  ingress:
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - /home/glaucon/dev/nginx-test-area:/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

it should work as expected.